# Interstitial Ad bound with tab bar

Tags: xcode, swift, interstitial

I am trying to implement an interstitial ad, the problem I have is it's not showing as a full screen ad, instead it's filling the current frame and leaving the tab bar.

```
    func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    interAdview = UIView()
    interAdview.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.addSubview(interAdview)
    interAd.presentInView(interAdview)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    interAdview.addSubview(close button)
```

Assuming it's the self.view.bounds that is causing the problem, but not sure how I can set the bounds to the superview ignoring the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting the interstitial from your root view controller, like following:

```
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!
    window?.rootViewController?.requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
```

Comment: Yes... and no.  
This will load the interstitial add full screen (over the tab bar), but doesn't have the same ability to load the add on demand.  It becomes very inconsistent.

Comment: You can try to present `ADInterstitialAd` on your root view controllers view. Something like this should work: `interAd.presentInView(window?.rootViewController?.view)`